# jsTree does not open_all even when loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

The recent integration of jsTree on my page has been a great success, despite my inability to open a single node from code. I start with an empty div in a jQueryUi dialog and a tree on it. When the user clicks on buttons, it opens the dialog and create the HTML for the tree in the variable "registerHTML". Then I use this code

```
$( "#registerTree" ).jstree().destroy();
$( "#registerTree" ).html(registerHTML);
$('#registerTree').bind("loaded.jstree", function () {
    $('#registerTree').jstree('open_all');
});
    $( "#registerTree" ).jstree({
    "checkbox" : {
    "keep_selected_style" : false
    },
    "plugins" : [ "checkbox" ]
});
```

Because I reload the dialog for every button clicked, I destroy the tree than recreate it completly. I read in previous questions that it was better to put the bind() or on() function before before setting jstree(). I don't understand why it wouldn't work and tried a lot of manners. Note that I have the checkbox plugin functional.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open all the node in your tree after the tree is completely loaded bind for the **ready.jstree** event.

```
$('#registerTree').bind("ready.jstree", function () {
    $('#registerTree').jstree('open_all');
}).jstree();
```

ready event is triggered after all nodes are finished loading in your tree.

Given an example in JSBIN - [Link](http://jsbin.com/moharu/5/)